# Trouble with running flutter app on an emulator

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

I'm learning flutter and I can't figure out how to run this app on the emulator. Like the emulator launches but the app doesn't appear on it. I figure it has something to do with the lack of a phone icon next it. The sdk api level is 31 and the api level on the emulator is 30.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctCAf.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of Emulators, select one then the emulator will run but it needs some time for first load like any device in first load Good luck.

Comment: I still can't select it.

Comment: You need to install new emulator from AVD manager in android studio that help you with that. or I can help remotely with TeamViewer or Anydisk